# Pandas Add Timestamp to file name during saving Data Frame in Excel

Tags: pandas, save, timestamp

While i am saving Data Frames in Excel format ("*.xlsx"), i would like to add time stamp to Excel file name.

How can i add run time time stamp to Data Frame while saving in Excel format while saving file using Pandas? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module. It's one of [the python standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html), you can access it by `pd.datetime` like below.

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output_{}.xlsx'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S'))) 
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2') 
writer.save()
```

And you can check [format code table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for the detail.

Comment: Thank you, but for some reason timestamp didn't appear in file name

Comment: Unfortunately not :-)

Comment: @Felix What about generated file name? Just 'output_.xlsx'? Please tell me the result of 'pd.datetime.today()' or 'pd.datetime.now()' and 'pd.datetime.today().strftime("%y%m%d-%H%M%S")' on python your consol.

Comment: pd.datetime.today()
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 6, 23, 4, 53, 50000)

pd.datetime.now()
Out[7]: datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 6, 23, 5, 24, 216000)

pd.datetime.today().strftime("%y%m%d-%H%M%S")
Out[8]: '160406-230542'

Comment: The name is output.xlsx only

Comment: @Felix Then maybe the code above is not applied correctly. Your file name 'output.xlsx' is old one. As you can see above, it should be  'output_.xlsx'(underbar) at least. It seems that you are using ipython, I recommend check whole code once again and rerun every line(I/O box).

Comment: The difference is that instead of 'output_{}.xlsx' i am using direct path to server. Might be this is a problem?

Comment: @Felix Hmm...In my point of view, if the original one(e.g. 'output.xlsx') worked fine, there should be a no problem with that kind of thing.

Comment: Same issue. File appears just with '_' underbar in name

Comment: For those who come across this thread, I used `writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output_{}.xlsx'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')), engine='xlsxwriter')` and it worked just fine.