# Pandas + Export to excel + Time Stamp + specify location

Tags: python, pandas, excel, export

I would like to export several df files to a single excel document.

Requirments:

- File name should include:

  custom name (using predefined variable, ie. month) + timestamp
- I want to specify path where file should be saved

Code below from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466372/pandas-add-timestamp-to-file-name-during-saving-data-frame-in-excel), does the job for storing several df in single file, but I cannot specify location.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output_{}.xlsx'.format(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S'))) 
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2') 
writer.save()
```

Code below from this question, does the job for saving the file with timestamp, but I can't find how to set path where to save it, or add several df to same file.

```
import time

TodaysDate = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
excelfilename = TodaysDate +".xlsx"

DataSet.to_excel(excelfilename, sheet_name='sheet1', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to post a comment, but I don't have enough reputation :(

I've tried:

```py
import pandas as pd
# pip install openpyxl required

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[1,1,1]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter("/Users/user/Desktop/output_{}.xlsx".format(pd.datetime.today().strftime('%y%m%d-%H%M%S'))) 
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer,'Sheet2') 
writer.save()
```

and it saves an excel file named: output_230803-122120.xlsx, with the two sheets as the pandas df.

which part of your requirements is not satisfied?

Comment: need to specify location where to store the file, you are right time stamps is written in file name

Comment: 'output_{}.xlsx' is the location, you could write an absolute path as "/Users/user/Desktop/output_{}.xlsx"

Comment: please write the comment I have just upvoted as solution, it works